# How to get Parent element in my custom tooltip class in WinUI?

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml, winui-3, winui

I have tried to get parent in my `custom` class:

```
FrameworkElement parent = this. PlacementTarget as FrameworkElement;

DependencyObject parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create `DependencyProperty` like this:

```cs
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls;

namespace ToolTipTests;

public class CustomToolTip : ToolTip
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SourceProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            nameof(Source),
            typeof(FrameworkElement),
            typeof(CustomToolTip),
            new PropertyMetadata(default));

    public CustomToolTip()
    {
        this.Opened += CustomToolTip_Opened;
    }

    public FrameworkElement Source
    {
        get => (FrameworkElement)GetValue(SourceProperty);
        set => SetValue(SourceProperty, value);
    }

    private void CustomToolTip_Opened(object sender, Microsoft.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.Source is FrameworkElement parent)
        {
            // Do something here...
        }
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```xml
<Button
    x:Name="ButtonControl"
    Content="Click">
    <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
        <local:CustomToolTip
            Content="?"
            Placement="Top"
            Source="{x:Bind ButtonControl, Mode=OneWay}" />
    </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
</Button>
```

Comment: AFAIK, there isn't. Sorry.